# Block specific urls with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want disable people putting #tabReglock in the urls and manually visiting a page that I removed from the menu.

I tried putting

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^#tabReglock
RewriteRule ^404.html$ - [F]

in the htaccess file, but it does not work

Comment: That cannot work. The anchor (the string following the #) is something that is handled _on the client side_ . It is never send to the server. So if your page contains that anchor, then obviously you cannot prevent people using that anchor. 
You could remove than anchor from your page, though ...

Comment: Hmm okay, what about just "TabReglock" this is still in the url, can this work ?

Comment: If that word ist "still in the url" as you say, so _not_ in the anchor (following the "#"), but before that, then sure, that is possible. Then you just need to implement a rewriting rule along the lines you did. A rule that matches that word inside the requested path or query string. Have a try. If that does not work as expected, then add your attempt to the question above, so that we can look over it. There is an "edit" link below your question, _use it ..._

Comment: It did not work unfortunately. So I went the long route and actually edited the page, and removed the code instead :)